# Rotation around a pivot point with OpenGL

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, 3d

I am trying to rotate an object about one of its side and already tried the common approach as found on the forums:

```
translate(-P);
rotate();
translate(P);
```

In `OpenGL` (reversing the order of translations/rotations), I used the following code:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-50, 50, 0);
        glRotatef(rotationCoord, 0, 1, 0);
    glTranslatef(50, -50, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
        glVertex3f(-50.0, 50.0, 0);
        glVertex3f(50.0, 50.0, 0);
        glVertex3f(50.0, -50.0, 0);
        glVertex3f(-50.0, -50.0, 0);
    glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

However, the rectangle that I am drawing doesn't seem to be rotating around one side as pivot.  (trying to set the left side as the pivot point and rotate around it). I made a screen capture  vid to show what kind of rotation I am getting right now. Here's the video:

http://youtu.be/VgEZ_rsG3xU

How do I set the pivot for this object so that it rotated around that point?

Comment: The choice of pivot is odd. The y-axis translation component has no effect, since you're rotating in the xz-plane. Is this what you intended?

Comment: @MarceloCantos : I didn't intend to rotate the around the Y-axis for now. Just X-axis. But the left hadn side of the rectangle seems to be moving whereas the pivot should be stationary. right?

Comment: `glRotatef(…, 0, 1, 0)` is a rotation around the y-axis (aka xz-plane), not the x-axis.

Comment: @MarceloCantos : Oops. I had to mention in the above comment that rotaiton has to be only around Y-axis for now, not X-axis. Apologies for the confusion. That said, with rotatio around Y-axis as well as it  is happening now, the pivot should be stationary about which I am not sure why.

Comment: Try reversing the order: T(P) R() T(-P). This is clutching at straws, but it would be good to at least eliminate the possibility.

Comment: @MarceloCantos : Tried already. Doesn't seem to work. Order I gues should be the same as in code because of post-multiplication in OpenGL

Comment: The code you posted works for me, it rotates the quad around the y axis, with the pivot on one side. I think you might be doing something wrong with the matrix stack somewhere. Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: As marcelo said: try Rotatef ( ... 0,0,1). You only have x,y coordinates, so you need to rotate around z.

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg : The code is nothing except what I have above. But here's pastebin of the draw method: http://pastebin.com/2QZqDYsH Other than this, there are no other operations that I am doing.

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from the

```
glTranslatef(0, 0, -10.0);
```

you're calling *after* the rotation. That means the (0,0,-10) is applied to the object coordinates (+-50,+-50,0) before they are transformed by anything else, so the quad is offset before it's being rotated.

Here's the code I used for testing, maybe you get something out of it:

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/ext.hpp>
using namespace glm;

void display(void)
{
  glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  GLfloat aspect = (float)g_Width / g_Height;
  mat4 eyeToCamera = perspective(45.f, aspect, g_nearPlane, g_farPlane); // projection
  mat4 cameraToWorld = lookAt(vec3(0, 0, -150), vec3(), vec3(0, 1, 0)); // view

  vec3 pivot(50, -50, 0);
  mat4 worldToObject = translate(pivot)
    * rotate(rotationAngle, vec3(0, 1, 0))
    * translate(-pivot); // model
  glLoadMatrixf(value_ptr(eyeToCamera * cameraToWorld * worldToObject));
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-50.0, 50.0, 0);
    glVertex3f(50.0, 50.0, 0);
    glVertex3f(50.0, -50.0, 0);
    glVertex3f(-50.0, -50.0, 0);
  glEnd();

  glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Note that I don't use any matrix stack functions, and I only set the GL_MODELVIEW matrix.

Comment: I needed to translate the translate the back by `-10` first because I have the projection matrix applied as above (which is needed for one of my subsequent operations that is to come later). I tried reducing the `z value` of the rectangle to change how far the rectangle is drawn and to see if that is creating a problem with the rotation. But even if the rectangle is at `-0.1`, I still don't get a fixed pivot. Because of OpenGL's post-multiplication, that translate by `-10` has to be there after rotation so as to make the rectangle fully visible inside the perspective projection.

Comment: I am not sure why that translate by `-10` is causing or how should I go around for fixed pivot with a rectangle still being shown in my perspective projection.

Comment: @user1240679 Put the `glTranslatef(0, 0, -10.0)` call before the rotation, i.e. directly after calling `glPushMatrix` above. That way the translation is applied after the object is rotated.

Comment: Superb! Thanks. A lil off-topic doubt to be cleared here. I have the vector positions of a rectangle (which is rotated in the real world - two Z vertices at Z=0, other two at Z=200). I want to get the rotation matrix from these vertices and apply it as I did above in my post (but instead of `glRotatef` will be using `glMultMatrix`). The question is here btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585424/creating-different-matrices-for-separate-asymmetric-frustums?noredirect=1#comment25670543_17585424 If you could just give a read to  comments discussion below that would give the context. Thanks